# How to solve the problem of inconsistent and disorganised data in a column after using a "Seperate by Delimiter" feature within excel or Power BI?

Tags: python, excel, powerbi, data-science, data-modeling

*!! This is my First Question over Stack Overflow so I apologize in advance for any ambiguous statement !!*

**PROBLEM: Inconsistent & Unorganised Data in every column, due to missing information in `input data`**

### Terminologies I will Use:

- *Input Data:* Data in a column before applying the "Separate by Delimiter" feature in Power BI
- *Output Data:* Data in a column after applying the "Separate by Delimiter" feature in Power BI

### ISSUE

---

*"I am working in Power BI over a dataset to structure it properly"*

***Input data of Dataset in Power BI***
[image: --View the input data of Dataset in Power BI--]

***output data of Dataset in Power BI***
[image: --View the output data of Dataset in Power BI--]

"As you could see in the pictures that I had a column in which multiple information was clubbed together *(Result of the autogenerated system)* in the mentioned format (title:info|title:info|title:info). I had Separated this Data using a Delimeter "|" in my case. but end up with Disorganised Data in separate columns due to missing pair of (title:info) in the original input data"

### Real Problem

---

"Every Column now has values which should belong to another Column. This has happened because of missing information(title:info) pairs in each cell of input data. Due to which multiple cells skips to next (title:info) pair for a column resulting in a column full of heterogeneous (title:info) pair"

**FOR EXAMPLE:**-

- Column named "Product Details.13" now have multiple pair values like "Qty Available:12", "Qty Invoiced:2", "Qty Invoiced:10", "Qty Canceled:15" instead of having only 1 homogenous set of "Qty Invoiced:0"

### Code for Reference

---

`M Language`

```
    let
        #"Split Column by Delimiter" = Table.SplitColumn(#"Reordered Columns1", 
        "Product Details", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter("|",QuoteStyle.Csv),
        {"Product Details.1", "Product Details.2", "Product Details.3",
        "Product Details.4", "Product Details.5", "Product Details.6", 
        "Product Details.7", "Product Details.8", "Product Details.9", 
        "Product Details.10", "Product Details.11", "Product Details.12", 
        "Product Details.13", "Product Details.14", "Product Details.15", 
        "Product Details.16", "Product Details.17", "Product Details.18", 
        "Product Details.19", "Product Details.20"})
    in
        #"Split Column by Delimiter"
```

**REQUEST for Solution**

- Please help me by recommending some ideas to deal with such heterogeneous data to make it consistent and Homogenous
- Help me to shift the invalid (title:info) pair to its Right Column without affecting Valid Data leaving a null value or a Blank in place of invalid data

**Expected Result**

- Columns with Homogenous data having similar (title:info) pairs consistently

**NOTES:**

- I had faced a similar issue in excel before
- I am aware that this issue has no relation to MS EXCEL or POWER BI incompetency

**SAMPLE:**

> As requested by @Mr. Ron, I am unable to provide any proper SAMPLE file in csv,xlsx,txt format because Stack Overflow does not allow this but I'll try to explain my issue with a simple reference

Expectation: Every (title:info) data should be synchronous throughout the
Column

```
|    Header-1    |    Header-2    |    Header-3    |    Header-4    |    Header-5    |
|    Name:abc    |    SKU:1234    |    order:a1    |   invoice:1a   |   Shipment:0   |
|    Name:eef    |    SKU:5678    |    order:b2    |   invoice:2b   |   Shipment:1   |
|    Name:ghi    |    SKU:1256    |    order:c3    |   invoice:3c   |   Shipment:0   |
|    Name:jkl    |    SKU:3478    |    order:d4    |   invoice:4d   |   Shipment:1   |
```

Reality: 3rd, 4th, and 5th column's (title:info) data is inconsistent throughout the Column

```
|    Header-1    |    Header-2    |    Header-3    |    Header-4    |    Header-5    |
|    Name:abc    |    SKU:1234    |    order:a1    |   Shipment:0   |  available:N0  |
|    Name:eef    |    SKU:5678    |    order:b2    |   invoice:2b   |   Shipment:1   |
|    Name:ghi    |    SKU:1256    |  available:N0  |   price:2344   | Discount:0.02% |
|    Name:jkl    |    SKU:3478    |    order:d4    |   invoice:4d   |   Shipment:1   |
```

I Hope Now, It'll be Clear

Comment: Please provide a data sample of the original data that demonstrates the problem as **text** that can be copied pasted. Be sure to anonymize the data if necessary.

Comment: Also, in what you've posted as the "input set", how can you tell to which data set a given data pair belongs?

Comment: What is the significance of the `â,¬` sequence in your data?

Comment: (1) As requested by @Ron Rosenfeld, I am unable to provide any proper SAMPLE file in csv,xlsx,txt format because Stack Overflow does not allow this but I had tried to explain my issue with a simple reference and updated the question with a Sample.


(2) input data belongs to Magento Platform, - However, I don't that it has any impact on the data.

(3) There is no significance of ```â,¬``` in my data, I'll remover them as soon as this issue gets solved.


I hope i've Answered your Querries Mr. @Ron

Comment: What you posted as should be enough, if I understand what you want. For future reference, in order to attach a file, you have to upload it to a sharing site, and then paste the link here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure exactly what you want for results, but to create, from the data you posted,

- a table where the headers are the data type
- assuming each row represents a particular product

If that's not what you want, please clarify.

You can:

- split the data on the pipe
- delete empty columns
- add a column to represent the row number
- unpivot the other columns
- split the value column on the colon
- pivot on the value column selecting "do not aggregate"

**M Code**
*read the comments for better understanding of the algorithm*
***change table name in line 2***

```
let

//just preprocessing to get from what you posted
//  to pipe-separated table
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table25"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"|    Header-1    |    Header-2    |    Header-3    |    Header-4    |    Header-5    |", type text}}),
    #"Demoted Headers" = Table.DemoteHeaders(#"Changed Type"),
    #"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Demoted Headers",{{"Column1", type text}}),
    #"Split Column by Delimiter" = Table.SplitColumn(#"Changed Type1", "Column1", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter("|", QuoteStyle.Csv), {"Column1.1", "Column1.2", "Column1.3", "Column1.4", "Column1.5", "Column1.6", "Column1.7"}),
    #"Changed Type2" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Split Column by Delimiter",{{"Column1.1", type text}, {"Column1.2", type text}, {"Column1.3", type text}, {"Column1.4", type text}, {"Column1.5", type text}, {"Column1.6", type text}, {"Column1.7", type text}}),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Changed Type2",{"Column1.1", "Column1.7"}),
    #"Trimmed Text" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Removed Columns",{{"Column1.2", Text.Trim, type text}, {"Column1.3", Text.Trim, type text}, {"Column1.4", Text.Trim, type text}, {"Column1.5", Text.Trim, type text}, {"Column1.6", Text.Trim, type text}}),
    #"Promoted Headers" = Table.PromoteHeaders(#"Trimmed Text", [PromoteAllScalars=true]),
    #"Changed Type3" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Promoted Headers",{{"Header-1", type text}, {"Header-2", type text}, {"Header-3", type text}, {"Header-4", type text}, {"Header-5", type text}}),

//Add index column to retain original row numbers
    rowNums = Table.AddIndexColumn(#"Changed Type3","Row Number",0,1,Int64.Type),

//Unpivot except for rowNum column
//remove Attribue column
    #"Unpivoted Other Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(rowNums, {"Row Number"}, "Attribute", "Value"),
    #"Removed Columns1" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Unpivoted Other Columns",{"Attribute"}),

//split by the colon delimiter
//set data types
    #"Split Column by Delimiter1" = Table.SplitColumn(#"Removed Columns1", "Value", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter(":", QuoteStyle.Csv), {"Value.1", "Value.2"}),
    #"Changed Type4" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Split Column by Delimiter1",{{"Value.1", type text}, {"Value.2", type text}}),

//Pivot on the Value.1 column
//Remove the row number column
    #"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(#"Changed Type4", List.Distinct(#"Changed Type4"[Value.1]), "Value.1", "Value.2"),
    #"Removed Columns2" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Pivoted Column",{"Row Number"})
in
    #"Removed Columns2"
```

[image]

Comment: Thank You so much, Mr. @ron_rosenfeld,
Your Technique of (Unpivoting -- Indexing -- Formating -- Pivoting) worked and resolved my problem.
Simple and Effetive.
The most crucial part of this strategy is to include the Row Number Column (Indexing) which i was omitting when I tried to deal with it in the first place through unpivoting.

Thank You :-)